# ArrayList sort by length

Tags: java

I want to sort an `ArrayList` of objects by the length of the vector
objects.

```
double[] s ={1,2,3,4};
double[] s2 ={1,2};
double[] s3 ={1,2,3};

Student[] Facultate ={new Student(s),new Student(s2)};
ArrayList<Student> FacultateList = new ArrayList<Student>(Arrays.asList(Facultate));
```

I want `FacultateList` to be ordered like `s2,s3,s`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(facultateList, new Comparator<Student>() {
    public int compare(Student a, Student b) {
        return a.getLength().compareTo(b.getLength());
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if this is the default way to sort students, make `Student` implement `Comparable<Student>`, implement the appropriate `compareTo` method in the class itself, and use `Collections.sort` without the custom comparator.

(Just an aside that will save you confusion later, the convention in Java is that variables start with a lowercase letter, so `facultateList`, not `FacultateList`.)